# Import Addresses from any email service

Tags: web-services, email

How to Import Addresses from Hotmail, Outlook, Yahoo!, Gmail and Others email services.
for sending them invitations from my site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [OpenInviter](http://openinviter.com/) is the easiest way of doing this.